# How to count the occurence of a word in multiple texts?

Tags: c++, tree

I have a Binary tree that stores all the words with their occurence in a text. Word as key and number of occurence as value

If i have multiple texts, do I create multiple trees ?

Also, I want to count the idf (inverse document frequency - how many times that word appears in all the texts).

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: *If i have multiple texts, do I create multiple trees ?* -- What do you mean by "multiple texts"?

Comment: I mean if I have multiple text files

Comment: Why not just use one tree and populate it with all the text for all files?

Comment: for example I have to count the occurence of a word in one text (hello, 20 times) and then the occurence of that word in all the texts (hello, 3 times in 5 texts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you will need a tree for each file to be able to know how many occurences of a word you have in each one.

Then, for the second part i can't understand if you need the total number of occurences of a word or the number of files that contain that word.
In each case you just need to cycle through all of your tree and look for that word.